# Xna will crash when I run my game - No Error

Tags: xna, crash

I don't know what is happening, so here is my code.
I am thinking that it is a problem with loading the model because when I comment that out it works. Just a very simple first person camera on a grid and I am trying to place a tree.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Series3D1
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        GraphicsDevice device;

        Effect effect;
        VertexPositionColor[] vertices;
        Matrix viewMatrix;
        Matrix projectionMatrix;
        int[] indices;

        float leftrightRot = MathHelper.PiOver2;
        float updownRot = -MathHelper.Pi / 10.0f;
        const float rotationSpeed = 0.3f;
        const float moveSpeed = 10.0f;

        // Set the position of the camera in world space, for our view matrix.
        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(50f,1.5f,-50f);
        Vector3 cameraLook;
        MouseState originalMouseState;
        SpriteFont font;
        Model tree1;

        private int terrainWidth = 100;
        private int terrainHeight = 100;
        private float[,] heightData;

        private bool flyMode = false;
        private bool JumpFlag = true;
        private int JumpCounter = 1;
        private float fallSpeed = -0.0f;
        private float jumpSpeed = 1.0f;
        private float movementSpeed = 1;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            Window.Title = "XNA";

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;

            effect = Content.Load<Effect>("effects"); SetUpCamera();

            Mouse.SetPosition(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);
            originalMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

            font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");

            tree1 = LoadModel("AlanTree");

            PlayMusic();

            UpdateViewMatrix();

            LoadHeightData();
            SetUpVertices();
            SetUpIndices();
        }

        private void UpdateViewMatrix()
        {
            Matrix cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(updownRot) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(leftrightRot);

            Vector3 cameraOriginalTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
            Vector3 cameraRotatedTarget = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalTarget, cameraRotation);
            Vector3 cameraFinalTarget = cameraPosition + cameraRotatedTarget;

            Vector3 cameraOriginalUpVector = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            Vector3 cameraRotatedUpVector = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalUpVector, cameraRotation);

            viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraFinalTarget, cameraRotatedUpVector);
            cameraLook = cameraFinalTarget;
        }

        private void DrawText()
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Game V1.0", new Vector2(20, 20), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "cameraLook: " + cameraLook, new Vector2(20, 40), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "cameraPostion: " + cameraPosition, new Vector2(20, 60), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "flyMode?: " + flyMode, new Vector2(20, 80), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        private Model LoadModel(string assetName)
        {

            Model newModel = Content.Load<Model>(assetName); foreach (ModelMesh mesh in newModel.Meshes)
                foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
                    meshPart.Effect = effect.Clone();
            return newModel;
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }

        private void SetUpVertices()
        {
            vertices = new VertexPositionColor[terrainWidth * terrainHeight];
            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < terrainHeight; y++)
                {
                    vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x, heightData[x, y], -y);
                    vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Color = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetUpIndices()
        {
            indices = new int[(terrainWidth - 1) * (terrainHeight - 1) * 6];
            int counter = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < terrainHeight - 1; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth - 1; x++)
                {
                    int lowerLeft = x + y * terrainWidth;
                    int lowerRight = (x + 1) + y * terrainWidth;
                    int topLeft = x + (y + 1) * terrainWidth;
                    int topRight = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * terrainWidth;

                    indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                    indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                    indices[counter++] = lowerLeft;

                    indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                    indices[counter++] = topRight;
                    indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                }
            }
        }

        private void LoadHeightData()
        {
            heightData = new float[1000, 1000];
            float tempHolder = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                    heightData[j, i] = tempHolder;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetUpCamera()
        {
            viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 10, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0),     new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
            projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,     device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            float timeDifference = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0f;

            MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
            if (currentMouseState != originalMouseState)
            {
                float xDifference = currentMouseState.X - originalMouseState.X;
                float yDifference = currentMouseState.Y - originalMouseState.Y;
                leftrightRot -= rotationSpeed * xDifference * timeDifference;
                updownRot -= rotationSpeed * yDifference * timeDifference;
                Mouse.SetPosition(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2,     graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);
                UpdateViewMatrix();
            }

            Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                moveVector += new Vector3(0, 0, -movementSpeed);
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                moveVector += new Vector3(0, 0, movementSpeed);
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                moveVector += new Vector3(movementSpeed, 0, 0);
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                moveVector += new Vector3(-movementSpeed, 0, 0);
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
            {
                if (flyMode == true)
                {
                    flyMode = false;
                }
                else if (flyMode == false)
                {
                    flyMode = true;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftControl))
                movementSpeed = 1.5f;
            else
                movementSpeed = 1.0f;
            if (flyMode)
            {
                if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
                    moveVector += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
                    moveVector += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            }
            else if (!flyMode) { 
                if (cameraPosition.Y > 1.5f) {
                    moveVector += new Vector3(0, fallSpeed, 0);
                    fallSpeed -= 0.1f;
                }
                else if (cameraPosition.Y < 1.5f)
                {
                    JumpCounter = 1;
                    fallSpeed = -0.0f;
                }
                if (JumpCounter == 10){

                }
                else if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) & JumpFlag == true){
                    moveVector += new Vector3(0, jumpSpeed, 0);
                    fallSpeed = -0.0f;
                    jumpSpeed += 0.001f;
                    JumpCounter += 1;
                }
            }
            AddToCameraPosition(moveVector * timeDifference);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        private void PlayMusic()
        {
            Song song = Content.Load<Song>("Peaceful");
            MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        }

        private void AddToCameraPosition(Vector3 vectorToAdd)
        {
            Matrix cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(leftrightRot);
            Vector3 rotatedVector = Vector3.Transform(vectorToAdd, cameraRotation);
            cameraPosition += moveSpeed * rotatedVector;
            UpdateViewMatrix();
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            device.Clear(Color.Black);

            RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
            rs.CullMode = CullMode.None;
            rs.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
            device.RasterizerState = rs;

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0,  vertices.Length, indices, 0, indices.Length / 3, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
            }

            DrawText(); //puts the debug text to the screen
            DrawModel();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        private void DrawModel()
        {
            Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.0005f, 0.0005f, 0.0005f) *     Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.Pi) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(19, 12, -5));

            Matrix[] treeTransforms = new Matrix[tree1.Bones.Count];
            tree1.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(treeTransforms);
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in tree1.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (Effect currentEffect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    currentEffect.CurrentTechnique = currentEffect.Techniques["Colored"];
                    currentEffect.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(treeTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *     worldMatrix);
                    currentEffect.Parameters["xView"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
                    currentEffect.Parameters["xProjection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
                }
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the crash in Visual studio or when you run the program on another machine? What line of code does it fail on? This one?
tree1 = LoadModel("AlanTree"); Or somewhere inside the LoadModel method? and what exception does it say? Does AlanTree exist in your content project in the root folder and is it set to build?

Comment: Try putting breakpoints at your code to find the line where it breaks. Like somehwere in your custom load model. Did you try just loading the model manually instead of that method?

Comment: Hello ZMan it is the Draw model method that is giving me trouble. The game crashes on start-up. If I take that out my game works, but I have to move the current.Effect to the draw method when I comment out the //DrawModel();.

Comment: And yes the model is in my root folder, but one thing is that I was getting an error with the .tga files for the texture of the tree. So 2 times pre-processor error, but I think I fixed it. Also to Menno Gouw yes I have tried loading the model manually and thank you to you two for helping :)